# Piecewise function not working

Tags: python, piecewise

I defined a piecewise function like this :

```
def C1(d,x):
    if ((x<d/2) and (x>-d/2)):
        return (1/d)
    else:
        return 0
```

But it always return me 0

```
In [23]: C1(1000,1)

Out[23]: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the division sign operator (/) performs integer division, meaning any decimal points are truncated, if the numerator and denominator are both integers.  So when you do (1/d), both 1 and d are integers so it does, for example, 1/1000 which is 0.001 but in integer division you lose the decimal so instead you get 0.  To fix this, make all of your defined numbers floats by adding a .0.  For example, (x < d/2.0), and (x > -d/2.0) and (1.0/d) This should give you the proper results.

Comment: The division operator behaves the way the questioner expected in Python 3.x. I just thought I should mention that.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake That is true, although based on the problem I assume the questioner is using 2.7.x

Comment: Likewise. I just wanted to clarify, should any other users stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try `from __future__ import division`

Here is the link to PEP 238 that explains this.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Comment: This is an important thing to mention but this answer could do with some additional explanation. With a suitable edit I would upvote this.

Comment: Basically, with the `__future__` `division` import, the `/` operator becomes "true" division; dividing an `int` by an `int` will always yield a `float` to ensure the result is (mostly) accurate (though floating point has its own quirks). With or without the import, `//` is floor division; for positive integers, this means truncating integer math as in C, for negative integers, it rounds down (so `1 // 2 == 0`, but `-1 // 2 == -1`).